# local variable 'items' referenced before assignment django

Tags: django

I have a view that is to show items in a cart for each user in a session.

Here is the

```
def cart(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "rp ", request.POST
        description = request.POST['description']
        print "Description is ", description
        price = request.POST['price']
        print "Price is ", price
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        print "Quantity is ", quantity
        client = request.user
        print "Client is ", client

        # items =  Cart.objects.get_or_create(client="client", description="description", price="price", quantity="quantity")
        item, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(client=client, description=description, price=price, quantity=quantity)
        item.save()

        try:
            items = Cart.objects.get(client=user)
            print "ITEMS", items
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            items = None
    # return HttpResponseRedirect('/selly/cart/')
    return render(request, 'selly/cart.html', {'items': items})
```

The result i get is 
"local variable 'items' referenced before assignment". And it is pointing to return render(request, 'selly/cart.html', {'items': items})

am confused

Comment: `items` is misleading since you could only ever possibly return one item by using `get`

Comment: i made the query to be outside the if block and the error gotten is global name 'user' is not defined at "items = Cart.objects.get(client=user)"

Answer (score 2):

Your `item` variable is only initialized in `if request.method == "POST"` block, but if you are not having POST method, the variable `item` is never initialized, thus when you call `render...` the `item` variable is undefined.

The easiest solution is to do the item query outside `if` block.

Comment: i made the query to be outside the if block and the error gotten is global name 'user' is not defined at "items = Cart.objects.get(client=user)"

Comment: The error couldn't have been more clearer, you don't have a variable called `user`, how could that code be valid?

Comment: The user is from django user model, i intend getting all items beloning to a particular user that is log in

Comment: Then it's `request.user` not `user`. I suggest you learning more python basics before jumping into django, that would save your time stuck on issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution you have to change client=user to client=request.user
as like this
try:
items = Cart.objects.get(client= request.user)
print "ITEMS", items
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
items = None
# return HttpResponseRedirect('/selly/cart/')
return render(request, 'selly/cart.html', {'items': items})